# Could not convert type C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am implementing custom paginator.
E.g.

```
vector<int> v{1,2,3,4};
for (auto page : Paginator(begin(v), end(v), 2)) {
    // For the first iteration i expect {1, 2}, and for the second {3, 4}
}
```

I have error in my code:

> `/home/alex/dev/main.cpp:32:28: error: could not convert ‘((Paginator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >*)this)->Paginator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >::data_.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin<std::vector<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, std::allocator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > > >, std::allocator<std::vector<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, std::allocator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > > > > >()’ from ‘std::vector<std::vector<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, std::allocator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > > >, std::allocator<std::vector<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, std::allocator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > > > > >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, std::allocator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > > >*, std::vector<std::vector<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, std::allocator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > > >, std::allocator<std::vector<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, std::allocator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > > > > > >}’ to ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >’`
>
> `return data_.begin();`

**My code**

```
template<class IterT>
class Paginator {
public:
    Paginator(IterT begin, IterT end, size_t sz) {
        pageSize_ = sz;
        const size_t dist = distance(begin, end);
        parts_ = dist / pageSize_;
        if (dist % pageSize_ != 0) {
            ++parts_;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= parts_; ++i) {
            IterT start = next(begin, (i - 1) * pageSize_);
            IterT finish  = next(begin, i * pageSize_);
            data_.push_back({start, finish});
        }
    }

    size_t size() const {
        return parts_;
    }

    IterT begin() {
        return data_.begin();
    }

    IterT end() {
        return data_.end();
    }


private:
    size_t pageSize_;
    size_t parts_;
    vector<vector<IterT>> data_;
};

template<class T>
void Print(const vector<T>& v) {
    for (auto i : v) {
        cout << i << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};


    for (auto i : Paginator<vector<int>::iterator>(begin(v), end(v), 2)) {
        Print(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: that looks like bad idea in general. you store iterators of vector which you push data to. latter invalidates all iterators plus return type doesn't match type of vector's internal iterator. not to mention that `begin` and `end` results are allowed to be different in future version of C++ standard, latter must support just the operator!=

Comment: You appear to be using [tag:C++17] -- in particular, `Paginator(begin(v), end(v), 2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IterT begin() {
    return data_.begin();
}

IterT end() {
    return data_.end();
}

vector<vector<IterT>> data_;
```

The type of `data_.begin()` is not `IterT`, it is `std::vector<std::vector<IterT>>::iterator`.

Those types don't convert.

The easy fix is to make `begin()` and `end()` return `auto`.

---

Your `data_` is a vector of vectors of iterators.

```
vector<int> v{1,2,3,4};
for (auto page : Paginator(begin(v), end(v), 2)) {
  // For the first iteration i expect {1, 2}, and for the second {3, 4}
}
```

here, `page` "should" be a `std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator>`.  If you want it to be a `std::vector<int>` you need to rework your design.

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= parts_; ++i) {
        IterT start = next(begin, (i - 1) * pageSize_);
        IterT finish  = next(begin, i * pageSize_);
        data_.push_back({start, finish});
    }
```

this code has bounds checking problems.  It is also ineffcient on non-random access iterators.

It generates a `vector<IterT>` with exactly 2 elements, one the start of the range one the end.

I suspect this isn't what you want.  What you want is a `vector< std::iterator_traits<IterT>::value_type >`.

```
template<class IterT>
class Paginator {
public:
  using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<IterT>::value_type;

  Paginator(IterT begin, IterT end, std::size_t sz):
    pageSize_(sz)
  {
    const std::size_t dist = std::distance(begin, end);
    parts_ = (dist+pageSize_-1) / pageSize_;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < parts_; ++i) {
      IterT start = std::next(begin, i * pageSize_);
      IterT finish  = std::next(begin, (std::min)( (i+1) * pageSize_, dist ));
      data_.emplace_back(start, finish);
    }
  }

  std::size_t size() const {
    return parts_;
  }
  auto begin() const {
    return data_.begin();
  }

  auto end() const {
    return data_.end();
  }


private:
  std::size_t pageSize_ = 0;
  std::size_t parts_ = 0;
  std::vector<std::vector<value_type>> data_;
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c80ce96012f1a49).

If you want to avoid copying stuff, you can by writing a `range_t` class that exposes `begin` and `end` and stores two iterators.  That would let the same test code work, without a copy of the data in the `Paginator` structure.

The OP contains some apparent [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) code, but the question asks for [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

To make the above work in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), add:

```
  using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<IterT>::value_type;
  using storage = std::vector<std::vector<value_type>>;
  using iterator = typename storage::iterator;
```

then

```
  iterator begin() const {
```

and

```
  iterator end() const {
```

Comment: in C++11 one would need  `auto begin() const ->` format of declaration and some other things for it to work, e.g. rearrange declarations in class and doing something with template parameter deduction fail

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie The OP appears to be using deduction guides based on what fails to compile.  But maybe the code chunks in the OP aren't actual code.

Comment: Maybe, though in his case compiler never reaches that point, it stops at failing in the method code as result the type is incomplete and it never reaches the loop. I was going after the the tag, but yeah, in his syntax that won't work in C++11.